# Get all objects back from parse in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

So I am trying to review all objects back from Parse.  I know parse has a limit of 1000, but I found some solutions that allows me to page through the results.  However, I can not get those solutions to work.  Wondering if someone has dealt with this before.

Declare a global variable for storing the complete data

```
private static List<ParseObject>allObjects;  
allObjects = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
     ParseQuery<ParseObject> query3 = ParseQuery.getQuery("HashTag");
                                query3.whereExists("Tag");
                                query3.setLimit(1000);
                               query3.findInBackground(getallobjects());
```

callback method:

```
   int limit = 1000;
    int skip = 0;
    private FindCallback<ParseObject> getallobjects() {
        return new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                allObjects.addAll(list);
                if (list.size() == limit) {
                    skip = skip + limit;
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery
                            .getQuery("HashTag");
                    query.setSkip(skip);
                    query.setLimit(limit);
                    query.findInBackground(getallobjects());
                }

                else  {
                    //you have full data in allobjects

                    for (int i = 0; i < allObjects.size(); i++) {}
                }
```

The issue seems to be that "getallobjects" is not resolved and I can't get the errors to go away.

Comment: Could you show us some of the attempts you have tried?

Comment: Yup - just edited the question.

Comment: @AndroidDev21921 you want to fetch more then 1000k data from parse table in one query ??

Comment: the parse limit is 1000 records returned.  I'm trying to 'page' through them.